# Creating a Cocoa Framework

Tags: cocoa, frameworks

I've created a working Cocoa framework which I wish to redistribute. The problem is however, it won't run outside of Xcode. I've read something about `@executable_path/../Frameworks`, which I did not include, because I don't know where to put it :/

Therefore I run my app in Xcode using the `DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH`  variable which works fine, but only in Xcode - if I try to run it on its own it crashes straight away and says `IMAGE NOT FOUND`.

I'm sure `@executable_path/../Frameworks` is what's missing, but I don't know where to put it.

Could anyone help me out please? :)

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by _running_ your framework? Frameworks usually don't have directly executable code. Also, did you read the Framework Programming Guide? http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Frameworks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000183-SW1 Maybe even just skimming through it will give you your answers.

Comment: of course I've read through it. The framework is imported into my app, but it crashes at startup. The guide also talks about setting `@executable_path/../Frameworks`, but I don't know where that is.

Comment: I've tried to set the "installation directory" parameter in the Project settings, but it still fails. It still says `dyld: Library not loaded:` and `Image not found`

Comment: Googling `@executable_path` yields this: http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?MoreOnEmbeddingFrameworks

Comment: Yes I've come across this article - it's old though and not on Xcode, but on Project Builder, so the interface is different. I'm sure it's in Xcode since it was Project Builder's successor, but I'm unable to find the parameters needed in it.

Comment: I've made a change to the installation directory parameter, but i get a different error now: `  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
 /Users/David/Documents/WriteIt! Studios/DAInternetActivationFrameworkTest/build/Release/DAInternetActivationFrameworkTest.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks: not a file`

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say the framework is "imported into my app"?  Is it in the Frameworks directory of your app bundle?

Comment: Yes it is in the framework directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I usually manage things:

1. In the framework's Xcode project, set the Installation Directory to @rpath
2. Add the framework to your application's Xcode project. Add a Copy Files build phase, select Frameworks in the Destination popup, and ensure your framework is added so it will be copied to your application's Frameworks directory when it is built.
3. Finally, in your project's settings, add @loader_path/../Frameworks to Runpath Search Paths.

Comment: I think it's not happy with the @executable_path - I've uploaded a screenshot of the run log here: http://web.me.com/david.schiefer/error.tiff

Comment: If you use @rpath there is no need for @executable_path, so I'm not sure why you're seeing this error.

Answer (score 0):

Are you actually copying the framework into your applications bundle?  Look for the folder called MacOS which is what contains the binary.  There should be another folder at the same level called Frameworks and it should have the framework inside it.

If it's not there you need to create a copy files build phase for the application that copies the framework into the Frameworks folder.

Comment: when clicking on "Show Contents", I see a Frameworks (it has my framework in it), Resources and MacOS.

Comment: OK, next thing is to find out where the application thinks it should be.  Open a terminal session, go into the MacOS directory and run `otool -L` on the binary.

Comment: First thought is that there is a misconfiguration in your linking process.  @executablepath/../Frameworks is not a library or a framework.  The reference should be to your actual framework not the folder containing it.

Comment: All the other frameworks in your posted tiff give you an example of what the end of the path should look like.

Comment: I've attempted changing the path, but now it won't apply it any more - even after cleaning the project, it still uses /../Frameworks as its path :S this is driving me nuts... :P

Comment: Please post the exact transcript of the link command of your application into your question.  There's something weird going on there.  To get the transcript, open the build window, set it to show "All Messages" then find the link line for the application.  Drag that line into a text editor and then paste it from there into the question.

Comment: it's too big to be pasted, so i uploaded it to my server instead: http://web.me.com/david.schiefer/log.txt

Comment: I think possibly the install_name option is incorrect.  It should point to the actual framework.  Going forward, what I would do now is create a fresh project to build your application and your framework and follow Apple's directions for configuring private frameworks to the letter.  http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Tasks/CreatingFrameworks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002258-106880-BAJJBIEF

Comment: my framework is not private, it's public. I'll check out the option now & i'll let you know how it went.

Comment: If it were a public framework, you'd want to install it in /Library/Frameworks or ~/Library/Frameworks not in your application bundle.

Comment: how does sparkle do it then? all i need to do for that is copy it into the bundle, that's far more convenient... :/