# Compiler cannot find my framework header file

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4.5

I have created my own .framework, which is having one .h file. When I use this framework, I am able to access all methods from this framework. It means its working fine. But when I try to access file .h (Which is my requirement), my application not able to find out header.

Should I do any additional setting in user header search path?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you add `-F <yourframework>.framework` to the compile command? Or, in Xcode, did you drag in a reference to the framework?

Comment: I have checked "Copy to destination" option

Comment: You still need to reference the framework AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

In your framework, set "installation directory" as @executable_path/../Frameworks.

Also, in your app project under your target -> build phases -> add a "Copy files" -> Frameworks -> and drop your framework.
This should do the trick.

[Creating a Cocoa Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2945394/creating-a-cocoa-framework)