# MAC app crashing on system other than it was built on

Tags: macos, cocoa

I am seeing a strange crash in my MAC app when I am running it on a machine on which the .app file was not built. If I run it on the machine where the .app file was built, it works fine.

I am setting the below relative path in my **Framework Search Paths**, **Runpath Search Paths** and **Library Search Path**

$(SRCROOT)/MAC/Library

Below is the message in crash logs:

```
Dyld Error Message:
 Library not loaded: @rpath/MyClient.framework/Versions/AMyClient
 Referenced from: /Users/USER/Desktop/RAM.app/Contents/MacOS/RAM
 Reason: image not found
```

Comment: you need copy framework build step, similar to copy resource files

Comment: @BryanChen Could you please explain this a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That means you linked against a framework but did not copy it to the app bundle. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2947313/153112) on how to do that.